# "j’ai rarement vu ça": Can it be ambiguously interpreted in two different ways?

Tags: sens

> Ces patients se remettent tous très rapidement de la grippe, **j’ai rarement vu ça**.
>   C’est sûrement grâce aux vaccinations.

Given the context, the speaker obviously means:

> J’ai rarement vu un système immunitaire aussi renforcé **chez les autres**.

But grammatically speaking, is it possible for it to be interpreted as:

> (On dit que) ces patients se remettent tous très rapidement de la grippe, (**encore que**) j’ai rarement vu ça **de mes propres yeux**.

If so, does this phrasing "j’ai rarement vu ça" sound ambiguous at all?

Comment: As a native speaker I find it not ambiguous at all. To express the idea in the last sentence, well we would say the full sentence. The shortcuts you propose completely change the meaning of the phrase.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence doesn't look ambiguous to me and means:

> J'avais jusque-là rarement vu des patients se remettre aussi rapidement de la grippe.